# Runnng lm function for every row in matrices

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix, lm

Hello Stackoverflow Users,

I am having trouble running an lm function in R on every row in my matrices, and I would really love if I didn't have to run it manually 1000 times. So basically I have 2 matrices with rows (1:1000) and cols (1:100), and I would like to run an lm function for each row in x for the representative row in y.

My code is:

```
sigmaianden=1
Beta=1
set.seed(seed=20)
xi=rnorm(100)
capn=100
capm=1000
xi.1=matrix(c(rep(c(xi),each=capm)),nrow=capm,ncol=capn)
epsiloni.1=NULL
for (i in 1:100000) {
epsiloni.1[i]=rnorm(1,0,sigmaianden*xi.1[i]^2)
}
epsiloni.11=matrix(epsiloni.1,nrow=1000,ncol=100)
yi.1=Beta*xi.1+epsiloni.11
```

Personally I was thinking something like:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
model[i]=lm(yi.1[i,1:100]~xi.1[i,1:100])
}
```

But that doesn't even give me a result. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. `lm` returns a `list`, so that what you want to do is to put your models to another list:

```
models <- vector("list", 1000)
for (i in 1:1000)
  models[[i]] <- lm(yi.1[i,1:100] ~ xi.1[i,1:100])
```

Then you may iterate again and extract `resid(models[[i]])` or `coef(models[[i]])` or anything else. However, now `models` is quite convenient to use, so that instead of `for` loops you can use just e.g.

```
R <- sapply(models, resid)
dim(R)
[1]  100 1000
```

or

```
C <- sapply(models, coef)
dim(C)
[1]    2 1000
```

Comment: Wow nice, I went to sleep after thinking about it for like an hour or so, and woke up to this. Cheers mate. So in order for me to take out all the residuals, estimates and standard deviation, I'll have to run a for-loop with each model [[i]] (summary for residuals) right?